# Is there a way to prevent Elastic Beanstalk from automatically opening up security groups to 0.0.0.0/0?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-security-group

**Problem**

I've been working with several small Elastic Beanstalk environments, both within and outside of VPCs. Every time I deploy, even if I specify security groups, Elastic Beanstalk creates new security groups for the instance(s) and ELB. These groups are open to 0.0.0.0/0. My organization's security rules catch these rules every time and remove them, and the security team follows up with me to ask if everything's alright.

**Question**

Can I configure Elastic Beanstalk to not open up the security groups to HTTP from anywhere on the internet prior to deploying?

Comment: When you create a new environment, are you making sure to go through the "Configure more options" path? In the "Instances" section you can choose your own security groups before you launch the new environment. You can uncheck the default security group that it creates and select your own security groups.

Comment: I tried to do that, and for some reason it still made the security groups.